# How to use std::find() with a 2d std: array?

Tags: c++

I am writing a function `CreateGrid()` that is trying to take a `std::string` and a 2d `std::array` as parameters, and put the individual characters from the `std::string` into the array. The rest of the array, if space is left, should be filled with the alphabetical characters A-Y, inclusive, in alphabetical order, providing they do not already appear in the `std::string`. Each character should only appear once in the final returned array.

So for input `string keyword = "HELO";`

The output would be:

```
H E L
O A B
C D F
```

Note the char 'E' only appears once.

I am trying to use `std::find()` to test whether all the chars in the alphabet A-Y (Z intentionally excluded) is already in the array, due to the keyword, before inserting it if it is not so that there are no duplicates. I am getting a compile error.

Code:

```
array<array<char,3>,3> CreateGrid(std::string keyword, array<array<char,3>,3> myArray)
{
  char letterToFind = 'A';

  for (int row = (keywordLength/3); row < 3; row++ )
  {
    for (int column = (keywordLength % 3); column < 3; column++)
    {
      auto it = std::find(begin(myArray), end(myArray), letterToFind);
      if ( it == end(myArray) ) // value not in array
      {
        myArray[row][column] = letterToFind;  //insert
      }
      letterToFind++;
    }
  }

  return myArray;
}

int main()
{
  array<array<char,3>,3> myArray = { {'H','E','L'}, {'O','+','+'}, {'+','+','+'} };
  CreateGrid("HELO", myArray);

  return 0;
}
```

I get a compile error for this line:

```
auto it = std::find(begin(myArray), end(myArray), letterToFind);
```

```
message : see reference to function template instantiation '_InIt std::find<std::_Array_iterator<_Ty,5>,char>(_InIt,const _InIt,const char &)' being compiled with[_InIt=std::_Array_iterator<std::array<char,3>3>,_Ty=std::array<char,3>]
```

How do I check to see if a `char` is in the array already, and if not then add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not normally trivial since you have nested arrays.  `std::find` can only return an iterator to the outer array, which isn't useful if you need to change the value in the inner array.

*However,* I notice that you don't actually *use* `it` other than to see if the sought element was located.  So, we can redefine the operation: instead of finding the element in an inner array that contains the value, it's sufficient to find any inner array that contains the value you're looking for:

```
auto it = std::find(
    begin(myArray), end(myArray),
    [letterToFind](array<char,3> const & inner) {
        return std::find(begin(inner), end(inner), letterToFind) != end(inner);
    }
);
```

If you found such an inner array, then you know that the value exists in the 2d array and can proceed.

Since you don't need the iterator, you could also use `std::any_of` instead:

```
bool found = std::any_of(
    begin(myArray), end(myArray),
    [letterToFind](array<char,3> const & inner) {
        return std::find(begin(inner), end(inner), letterToFind) != end(inner);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `myArray` parameter is an array containing `array<char,3>` elements.  You are using `find()` to search only that outer array.  So `begin(myArray)` will return an iterator that enumerates `array<char,3>` elements, and you can't compare a single `char` to a whole `array<char,3>`, which is why your `find()` call does not compile.  You would have to loop though the outer array calling `find()` on each inner array instead.

A simpler way to implement this is to use a lookup table to keep track of the characters that you have already seen, eg:

```cpp
const size_t MaxRows = 3;
const size_t MaxColumns = 3;
const size_t MaxCells = MaxRows * MaxColumns;

using gridRow = std::array<char, MaxColumns>;
using grid = std::array<gridRow, MaxRows>;

grid CreateGrid(const std::string &keyword)
{
    grid g;
    std::array<bool, 256> lookup{};
    size_t numFilled = 0;

    for(size_t i = 0; (i < keyword.size()) && (numFilled < MaxCells); ++i)
    {
        if (!lookup[static_cast<unsigned char>(keyword[i])])
        {
            lookup[static_cast<unsigned char>(keyword[i])] = true;
            g[numFilled / 3][numFilled % 3] = keyword[i];
            ++numFilled;
        }
    }

    for(char ch = 'A'; (ch <= 'Y') && (numFilled < MaxCells); ++ch)
    {
        if (!lookup[static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)])
        {
            g[numFilled / 3][numFilled % 3] = ch;
            ++numFilled;
        }
    }

    return g;
}

int main()
{
    grid myArray = CreateGrid("HELO");
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/fT0dfl)

Alternatively, you can use a [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) or [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) for the lookup:

```cpp
#include <unordered_set>

const size_t MaxRows = 3;
const size_t MaxColumns = 3;
const size_t MaxCells = MaxRows * MaxColumns;

using gridRow = std::array<char, MaxColumns>;
using grid = std::array<gridRow, MaxRows>;

grid CreateGrid(const std::string &keyword)
{
    grid g;
    std::unordered_set<char> lookup;
    size_t numFilled = 0;

    for(size_t i = 0; (i < keyword.size()) && (numFilled < MaxCells); ++i)
    {
        if (lookup.insert(keyword[i]).second)
        {
            g[numFilled / 3][numFilled % 3] = keyword[i];
            ++numFilled;
        }
    }

    for(char ch = 'A'; (ch <= 'Y') && (numFilled < MaxCells); ++ch)
    {
        if (lookup.insert(ch).second)
        {
            g[numFilled / 3][numFilled % 3] = ch;
            ++numFilled;
        }
    }

    return g;
}

int main()
{
    grid myArray = CreateGrid("HELO");
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/6fWkxt)